# How to list column without group by in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, select

So in SQL, I have a table artists that has (artist_id, artist_name, artist_hotness, artist_familiarity) I also have a table songs that has (song_id, song_name, album_id, artist_id).

I'm trying to list each artist and their longest song, along with the title of the song. I currently have

```
select artist_name, song_title, max(duration) as length
from artists natural inner join songs
group by artist_name, song_title;
```

but this obviously lists each song by that artist and its duration. However, I can't not group by song_title because it is in the select clause and is not an aggregate function.

In MySQL I've tried running the above query but only grouping by artist_name, but then the result shows the correct duration but NOT the correct song title.

Comment: which version of mySQL are you using?

Comment: I'm not sure specific version. Using mySQL on MariaDB server using SSH client

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following using window function `row_number()`. In any case artist have more than one song with same duration then just switch `row_number()` with `dense_rank()`.

```
select
    artist_name, 
    song_title, 
    duration
from
(
    select 
        artist_name, 
        song_title, 
        duration as length,
        row_number() over (partition by artist_name order by duration desc) as rnk
    from artists 
    natural inner join songs
)
where rnk = 1 ;
```